Why did Belos not implement his plan sooner?
In the third season of The Owl House, Belos, upon learning from the Collector that

 Titan magic could cancel out the Collector's own powers,

decided to take advantage of this to take over the body of the Titan by merging with its heart.
However, Belos had had the Titan heart in his throne room for at least 50 years—indeed, it was implied to be a part of how he transformed himself into his current state—and had apparently had his possession-capable form that whole time. Besides the idea that a Titan could resist the Collector, Belos had not learned anything new, and so presumably should have been aware that he could take control of the Titan and implement his agenda of destroying witches and demons sooner.
Why did Belos wait to implement this plan, and indeed pursue a rather longer and more laborious plan involving branding all witches (the Day of Unity)?


Belos had had the Titan heart in his throne room for at least 50 years

Apparently, Belos wasn't aware of the heart's true nature, and that he could use it to take control of the entire Boiling Isles. From Wikipedia's plot summary of the episode:

The Collector reveals to Raine Whispers, who is currently being possessed by Emperor Belos, that Titan magic supersedes the Collector's, and within Belos' castle lies the still-beating heart of King's father, the Titan whose body became the Boiling Isles.

TV Tropes (obligatory time-sink warning) concurs:

The beating heart that has been sitting in the throne room ends up coming [into] play when Belos realizes that A) it's the Titan's heart and B) Titan magic cancels out the Collector's magic.

This might sound improbable, but I think it can be explained away by Belos' xenophobia. He doesn't care to learn anything about the Boiling Isles or its inhabitants, he just wants to destroy it all.

If and when I have more time, I'll rewatch that particular scene and see if there's any dialogue that confirms more explicitly that Belos didn't know what the heart was beforehand.

Belos was very interested in learning about the parts of the Isles that he could use to enact his plans, though, from basilisks' ability to drain magic to the Collector's prison to Titan glyphs and even Titan's blood.

So while it certainly might be plausible that he would never be interested in learning grudgby rules or the different types of demons, I don't see how he would not be interested in something that was clearly related to the Titan (it's located in the middle of the Titan's rib cage, what else would it be?)
